# Text Was Truncated or One or More Characters Has No Match in the Target Code Page

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

For the life of me, I cannot seem to get past the following error:

Error: 0xC020901C at Import Data - APA, APA Workbook [2]: There was an error with APA Workbook.Outputs[Excel Source Output].Columns[Just] on APA Workbook.Outputs[Excel Source Output]. The column status returned was: "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".

Error: 0xC020902A at Import Data - APA, APA Workbook [2]: The "APAC Workbook.Outputs[Excel Source Output].Columns[Just]" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "APA Workbook.Outputs[Excel Source Output].Columns[Just]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component."

I have an SSIS package that is trying to load data from an Excel file into a SQL Server table.  I understand SSIS takes a "Snapshot" of the data and uses this to build the column sizes.  My database column for this column is:  nvarchar(512).

So some things I have done to try and rectify this are as follows:

1. Added "IMEX=1" to the extended properties of the Excel Connection string
2. Created an Excel file with 10 rows and each row has 512 characters in this "Just" column so that SSIS will recognize the size
3. Went into the Advanced Editor for the Source, then "Input and Output Properties".  Then went to the Just column and changed DataType to "Unicode String [DT_WSTR] and changed the Length to 512

After I did the above, I ran the code and the 10 rows of data were imported with no issue.  But when I run it against the real Excel file, the error appears again.

I have found that if I add a column to find the character length of the column, then sort by that, putting the largest first, the code works.  But if the file is as sent by the user, it errors out

I would appreciate any help on how to solve this, as all of my Google searches state the above would work, but unfortunately it is not.

Comment: I think your solution 3 should work, what column(s) have you resized, external, output or both?

Comment: I went into Input and Output Properties.  Then into "Excel Source Output", then went into "Output Columns" and changed the values there.  Changing the values in "External Columns" never stays.  It always goes back to 255.  Everything I have read says to only worry about the "Output Columns".

Comment: Another thing you can try is select error output and redirect the rows with truncation errors

Comment: I have done that, but I still need these values to import.  I can't just ignore them because of truncation when they shouldn't be truncated as their length is well under the database size for the column

Comment: Try saving the problem worksheet as a .csv file and then open it in VS Code with the "Rainbow CSV" extension to see if there are any extra columns involved. If that's the case you could add some dummy columns to the input columns and just ignore them in later processing stages.

Comment: You don't need to ignore the columns with truncation errors, you can redirect them and deal with them in another transformation.

Comment: Thank you for posting that sorting by length did work.  I realize it didn't help you, but after 2 days of banging my head against this error, it fixed it for me (I just need a one-shot to work) and I am grateful :)